# How to create a dataframe along with schema from the individual values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have some individual values with data and i have to convert it into dataframe. and i tried the below . Only one row output will come.

```
val matchingcount= 3
val notmatchingcount=5
val filename=h:/filename1

import spark.implicits._
val data=Seq("+filename+","+matchingcount+","+notmatchingcount+").toDF("ezfilename","match_count","non_matchcount")
data.show()

throwing error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArguementException : requirement failed : the number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): value
New column names (8) : ezfilename,match_count,non_matchcount
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! The code that does what you want is the following:

```
val matchingcount= 3
val notmatchingcount=5
val filename="h:/filename1"

import spark.implicits._
val data=Seq((filename,matchingcount,notmatchingcount)).toDF("ezfilename","match_count","non_matchcount")
data.show()

+------------+-----------+--------------+
|  ezfilename|match_count|non_matchcount|
+------------+-----------+--------------+
|h:/filename1|          3|             5|
+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

There are 3 key differences between your code and the code above here:

- In scala, a string has to be surrounded by `"` characters. So I've added these characters to `val filename=`
- You were correct in the fact that you could use a `Seq` to use the `toDF` method after imports `spark.implicits._`, but each element of the string would represent one row of the dataframe. So instead of creating a dataframe with 3 columns you were creating one with 1 element. The way you can create 3 columns is by adding tuples inside of your `Seq`. So notice the difference between `Seq(bla,bla,bla)` and `Seq((bla, bla, bla))` where the latter is the correct one. You can also create multiple rows like this by doing: `Seq((bla, bli, blu), (blo, ble, bly))`.
- In Scala, the way you access a variable's value is by simply writing the variable's name. So writing `filename` instead of `"+filename+"` is the correct way of doing that.

Hope this helps!